# FluentValidation ValidateAsync override never shows a failure

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, fluentvalidation

I am running a Blazor Server app and im using `FluentValidation` and `PPioli.FluentValidation.Blazor` packages and i'm not able to reliably get the results back to set other properties. When i override ValidateAsync, the returned results are always valid with no errors, even though the validation results are triggered in the UI.

```
public class FormValidator : AbstractValidator<FormModel>
    {
        public FormValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(V => V.Username)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Username cannot be empty");

        }

        public override Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<LoginModel> context, CancellationToken cancellation = default)
        {
            var result = Task.FromResult(new ValidationResult());
            return base.ValidateAsync(context, cancellation);
        }

    }
```

`result.Result.IsValid` is ALWAYS true, even when validation is failing and showing in the UI.

`result.Result.Errors.Count` is ALWAYS 0, even when validation is failing and showing in the UI.

There is no indication in the results variable that any validation is failing, even though it clearly is failing

Comment: Is the version of the fluentvalidator compatible with your version of .net? I can vaguely remember having the same problem with .net6 not being supported yet.

Comment: Im running .Net 5 currently